# Use Gauss-Jordan elimination to solve a linear system for non-negative integer solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, integer-programming

I know how to solve a set of linear equalities with Gauss-Jordan elimination, but this gives me all real solutions. Is there a way to constrain all variables to the non-negative integers, i.e., $x \in \mathbb N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). This is a huge complex field, with some of the common approaches being [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) and [cutting plane methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting-plane_method). See the wiki links for more information.